# Output current of TLV713 regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm using TLV71333P-Q1 to regulate the input voltage of 5 V to get the output of 3.3 V.

It says in the datasheet that in normal operation, "*The input voltage is greater than the nominal output voltage added to the dropout voltage*" and when I looked up in the Electrical characteristics table there's a field of dropout voltage (V<sub>DO</sub>).

[image: Electrical characteristics table]

`5V - 3.3V = 1.7 V` is clearly greater than all of the above values but V<sub>DO</sub>s are different as the different of I<sub>OUT</sub>.

The question is how can I determine the I<sub>OUT</sub> of this regulator. And if my input voltage is lower than 5 V (may be 4 V or 4,5 V), how can I determine the V<sub>DO</sub>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I<sub>OUT</sub> is determined by the load of the LDO and is between 0 and 150 mA.

The minimum input voltage that should be provided is:

V<sub>IN</sub> = V<sub>OUT(nom)</sub> + V<sub>DO(max)</sub>

In your case: 3.3V + 0.54V = 3.84V

Answer (score 1):

Plot Vdo max / Iout  ratio vs Vout. That is the effective series resistance or Ron at those limits.The spec graphs it and shows that  Ron is 2.43 ohms at the lower voltage and 1.53 at the higher voltage. This is due to Vgs-Vt for the internal FET. Then you can analyze the worst case Vdo margin and power dissipation with your  load R.

Then you can extrapolate or interpolate (NOMINAL) Ron at nearby Voltages. BUT USE WORST CASE FROM THE TABLES.